# something informs something to something

Tags: sentence-meaning

Could you please explain what "these goals informed the reaction to suggestion" mean ?

I think the pattern is that **something informs something to something** but I couldnt find out its meaning.

> Furthermore, in the lives of the impoverished masses, stability was of
>   the utmost importance. Maintenance of one's job, one's family life,
>   one's quality of living were the utmost goals of the commoner, and
>   **these goals informed the reaction to suggestion** that the principles upon which everyday life was thought to be based were no
>   longer valid. In the face of this threatened instability and change,
>   common Europeans often turned to the Church for guidance, for the
>   Church had been the most stable feature of the previous millennium,
>   defining the phenomena of the often hard to understand natural world,
>   and in essence telling the common churchgoer what to believe.

http://www.sparknotes.com/history/european/scientificrevolution/section10.rhtml

Comment: I think there's a copyediting error in that bolded passage: it would better read "*these goals informed the reaction to **the** suggestion that*...".

Answer (score 1):

You misinterpreted the *to*. It is not a direct object in the phrase as you thought, it is part of  the direct object *the reaction to suggestion*. The entire phrase is the direct object, a reaction is always a reaction **to** something. It doesn't have anything to do with the verb *inform* here.

The clause breaks down into:

> - these goals **(subject)**
> - informed **(verb)**
> - the reaction to suggestion that the principles upon which everyday life was thought to be based were no longer valid **(direct object)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please tell me any synonym for the verb inform ? Can I say "show" or "suggest" ?

Comment: @Mrt Though I am not 100% certain, I think in this case it means "to influence something such as an opinion or decision". You can find that definition under "business English" here: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inform?source=chromex-tb-ex&q=inform